# Unmarshal JSON tagged union in Go

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm trying to demarshal the JSON requests of [Google Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/create#provide-fulfillment). These have arrays of tagged unions like this:

```
{
    "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
    "inputs": [{
      "intent": "action.devices.QUERY",
      "payload": {
        "devices": [{
          "id": "123",
          "customData": {
            "fooValue": 74,
            "barValue": true,
            "bazValue": "foo"
          }
        }, {
          "id": "456",
          "customData": {
            "fooValue": 12,
            "barValue": false,
            "bazValue": "bar"
          }
        }]
      }
    }]
}

{
    "requestId": "ff36a3cc-ec34-11e6-b1a0-64510650abcf",
    "inputs": [{
      "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
      "payload": {
        "commands": [{
          "devices": [{
            "id": "123",
            "customData": {
              "fooValue": 74,
              "barValue": true,
              "bazValue": "sheepdip"
            }
          }, {
            "id": "456",
            "customData": {
              "fooValue": 36,
              "barValue": false,
              "bazValue": "moarsheep"
            }
          }],
          "execution": [{
            "command": "action.devices.commands.OnOff",
            "params": {
              "on": true
            }
          }]
        }]
      }
    }]
}

etc.
```

Obviously I can demarshal this to an `interface{}` and use fully dynamic type casts and everything to decode it, but Go has decent support for decoding to structs. Is there a way to do this elegantly in Go ([like you can in Rust](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html) for example)?

I feel like you could almost do it by reading demarshalling to this initially:

```
type Request struct {
    RequestId string
    Inputs    []struct {
        Intent   string
        Payload  interface{}
    }
}
```

However once you have the `Payload interface{}` there doesn't seem to be any way to deserialise that into a `struct` (other than serialising it and deserialising it again which sucks. Is there any good solution?

Comment: What's the union? What types do you need to switch between during unmarshaling?

Comment: The `payload` field contains different types. Sorry I realise the examples I gave weren't obvious - I'll update it.

Comment: To be clear - the type of `payload` depends on the value of `intent`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/u0tjSvrlp9Z

Comment: `json.Unmarshal` will unmarshal the json by the tags, so if you have a "union" of , say 100 possible types, you can have a struct with 100 fields with the correct tags or fieldnames and json.Unmarshal will unmarshal the json into the correct field.

Comment: @mkopriva That's a hack that only works for this specific example. It doesn't work if you have a field with the same name with two different types for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of unmarshaling `Payload` to an `interface{}` you can store it as a `json.RawMessage` and then unmarshal it based on the value of Intent.  This is shown in the example in the json docs:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage_unmarshal

Using that example with your JSON and struct your code becomes something like this:

```
type Request struct {
    RequestId string
    Inputs    []struct {
        Intent   string
        Payload  json.RawMessage
    }
}

var request Request
err := json.Unmarshal(j, &request)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("error:", err)
}
for _, input := range request.Inputs {
    var payload interface{}
    switch input.Intent {
    case "action.devices.EXECUTE":
        payload = new(Execute)
    case "action.devices.QUERY":
        payload = new(Query)
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(input.Payload, payload)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error:", err)
    }
    // Do stuff with payload
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made https://github.com/byrnedo/pjson for exactly this reason.

So in your case you'd have:

```golang
type Input interface {
    // Variant func is required
    Variant() string
}

type ExecuteInput struct {
    Payload struct {
        // is any just to avoid typing it for this example
        Commands []any `json:"commands"`
    } `json:"payload"`
}

func (q ExecuteInput) Variant() string {
    return "action.devices.EXECUTE"
}

type QueryInput struct {
    Payload struct {
        // is any just to avoid typing it for this example
        Devices []any `json:"devices"`
    } `json:"payload"`
}

func (q QueryInput) Variant() string {
    return "action.devices.QUERY"
}

type Inputs []Input

func (i Inputs) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return pjson.New(Inputs{}, pjson.WithVariantField("intent")).MarshalArray(i)
}

func (i *Inputs) UnmarshalJSON(bytes []byte) (err error) {
    *i, err = pjson.New(Inputs{ExecuteInput{}, QueryInput{}}, pjson.WithVariantField("intent")).UnmarshalArray(bytes)
    return
}

type Request struct {
    RequestId string `json:"requestId"`
    Inputs    Inputs `json:"inputs"`
}
```

[Try it on go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/eAV-oc3ziMd)